# Type-level constraints in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-level-computation

I'm trying to encode term algebra as a data type in Haskell for further use in an algorithm. By term algebra I mean a set of terms which are either *variables* or *functions* applied to other terms. The functions with zero arguments are *constants* (but that's actually does not matter here).

Firstly, one would need the following GHC language extensions to replicate my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds,
TypeApplications,
TypeFamilies,
TypeOperators,
StandaloneKindSignatures,
UndecidableInstances#-}
```

and the following imports:

```
import qualified GHC.TypeLits as GTL
import Data.Kind
```

The direct way to encode terms (the first one I took):

```
data Term where
  Var :: String -> Term
  Func :: String -> Integer -> [Term] -> Term
```

where by `String` I want to encode the name, by `Integer` the arity and by `[Terms]` the list of arguments of a function.
Then I want to be sure that the list of terms as arguments have the same length as an arity.
The first idea is to use smart constructors, but I would like to encode such constraints on a type level. So the second idea would be to create type-level naturals, lists of a specified length and the data type where these numbers coincide:

```
data Z = Z
data S a = S a

data List n a where
    Nil  :: List Z a
    Cons :: a -> List m a -> List (S m) a

data WWTerm where
  WWVar :: String -> WWTerm
  WWFunc :: String -> m -> List m WWTerm -> WWTerm
```

My question here is the following: is there a way to impose type-level constraints using ordinary lists at the same time via 1) creating special type-families, 2) creating special type classes, or 3) via constraints in data types?

Regarding my attempts, I wrote the following:

```
type MyLength :: [Type] -> GTL.Nat
type family MyLength xs where
  MyLength '[] = 0
  MyLength (x':xs) = 1 GTL.+ (MyLength xs)

data QFunc n l where
  QFunc :: (MyLength l ~ n) => String -> (n :: GTL.Nat) -> l -> QFunc n l
```

Unfortunately, this part of code doesn't compile for the following reasons:

```
Expected a type, but ‘n :: Nat’ has kind ‘Nat’
...

Expected a type, but ‘l’ has kind ‘[*]’
...
```

Are there any thoughts on how to approach my goal?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with ordinary lists: Haskell does not (currently) have full dependent types, only GADTs, and with those you can't inspect the list value -- only the list type. You therefore need a type which exposes the list length, as you did in the previous solution.

Comment: If you're willing to experiment with high-tech, Liquid Haskell can express constraints on values of arbitrary types. This is probably overkill though, and you might be better served by an abstract data type that packages up the length and the list once for all, with a couple functions that promise to preserve the invariant and then you never have to think about it.

Comment: @chi, I see your point, thanks. I was just wondering if there is a way around it through type families because sometimes (as far as I know) they can mimic dependent types.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia, you mean the functions that I use throughout the program which preserve that correspondence between an arity and a list length?